# Setting to limit allowed time for an IIS 7 request to complete?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net, .net-3.5, request

In IIS 7, you can view the worker processes and see which requests are currently executing. I am encountering some requests that remain in the "ExecuteRequestHandler" stage for hours - basically until the application pool is recycled. I am unsure why this is happening but it appears to correlate with "connection_dropped" errors in the httperr.log file.

I want to ensure these requests aren't tying up resources (we're seeing memory spikes as well, though I can't necessarily tie the two together; CPU for the requests is 0%), so is there a way to limit the amount of time a request can have? I found one for classic ASP but nothing for .NET.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to modify the `executionTimeout` attribute of the `httpRuntime` in either your application `web.config` or in `machine.config` to an appropriate value. [Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. It says the default is 110, so I wonder if something is interfering. Debug should already be off.

Comment: This does seem to be the proper way of setting things, but it unfortunately did not resolve my issue.

Comment: How did it not resolve the issue?

Comment: The requests continue to persist in IIS for many hours.